# Data missing in a degraded zfs pool

Tags: zfs

This is my first attempt to create a zfs pool manually under Proxmox.

I have created a raidz2 zfs pool with 5 drives (4 WD RED 1TB NAS drives and 1 old 1TB Seagate). I also forgot to specify 2 spares, so I ended up with 5 drives in the pool.
One of the HD stopped working properly (sometimes showing as FAULTED, sometimes as UNAVAIL) and the pool became degraded.

```
    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    storage                                       DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ata-ST31000524AS_9VPCK7DZ                 ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD10EFRX-68FYTN0_WD-WCC4J1AKT5C7  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD10EFRX-68FYTN0_WD-WCC4J1AKTPZ9  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD10EFRX-68FYTN0_WD-WCC4J2RS3EP8  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD10EFRX-68FYTN0_WD-WCC4J2YX0L9Z  FAULTED      0     0     1  too many errors
```

I have also created a couple of subdirectories in order to separate the data from the VM's (eg: /storage/share/iso. /storage/share/Movies ...)

storage/share is to be mounted and shared via NFS by a VM.
storage/vmstorage is where the vm's are stored.

```
NAME                                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
storage                               415G  2.19T   170K  /storage
storage/repos                         170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/repos
storage/share                         400G  2.19T   397G  /storage/share       
storage/share/Backups                 170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/share/Backups
storage/share/BuildDrop               170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/share/BuildDrop
storage/share/Movies                  170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/share/Movies
storage/share/Software                170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/share/Software
storage/share/Tv Shows                170K  2.19T   170K  /storage/share/Tv Shows
storage/share/iso                    3.21G  2.19T  3.21G  /storage/share/iso
storage/vmstorage                    14.8G  2.19T   199K  /storage/vmstorage
storage/vmstorage/subvol-100-disk-1   850M  7.17G   850M  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-100-disk-1
storage/vmstorage/subvol-101-disk-1   894M  7.13G   894M  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-101-disk-1
storage/vmstorage/subvol-102-disk-1  1.06G  6.94G  1.06G  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-102-disk-1
storage/vmstorage/subvol-103-disk-1   667M  7.35G   667M  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-103-disk-1
storage/vmstorage/subvol-104-disk-1   460M  7.55G   460M  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-104-disk-1
storage/vmstorage/subvol-108-disk-0   795M  7.22G   795M  /storage/vmstorage/subvol-108-disk-0
```

I was able to access the shared folder from the network and use it as a normal network share with no issues, until the disk broke.
I had some data under the /storage/share/* that just disappeared. VM's are fine.

Shouldn't the data still be accessible even in a degraded mode?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: why the downvote? would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage/share dataset got somehow unmounted.
Mounting the zfs dataset again solved the issue !